# React-Native: createRefCannot add property value, object is not extensible

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've just started working with React-Native and TypeScript:

```js
export default class List extends PureComponent<Props, object> {
   private flatListRef: React.RefObject<FlatList<any>>;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.flatListRef = React.createRef<FlatList<any>>();
  }
  
  render() {
    const { data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] } = this.props;
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          paddingBottom: 60,
          height: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <FlatList
          ref={this.flatListRef}
          data={data}
          ListHeaderComponent={
            <Image
              style={styles.headImg as ImageStyle}
              source={{ uri: ''}}
              resizeMode="contain"
            />
          }
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            return `${item.id + index + 2}`
          }}
          stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
        >
        </FlatList>

      </View>
      );
   }
}
```

I ran into an error:

[image]

But when I use Callback Refs, there's no error.

I have no idea why React.createRef does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your code like this.

```
     private flatListRef: React.RefObject<FlatList<any>>;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.flatListRef = React.createRef(); // modified
  }
```

mine have no error

Answer (score 0):

You can unfreeze this object by reassigning it in componentWillMount:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.refs = {}
}
```